# VS2010 auto-format for ASM files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, assembly

I have the following `.asm` file in my solution:

```
doTimerAsm PROC EXPORT
pushfd             ; backup flags register (4 Bytes)
pushad             ; bakcup general purpose registers (8*4 Bytes)
mov eax, [esp+24h] ; load interrupt handler pointer
push [esp+28h]     ; push handler parameter
call eax           ; invoke interrupt handler
popad              ; after return from interrupt handler, restore general purpose registers
popfd              ; restore flags register
add esp, 08h       ; pop interrupt handler pointer and the parameter
ret                ; resume
doTimerAsm ENDP
```

I ran the VS auto-format on it expecting it to just indent the middle lines. Insead, it produced the following:

```
doTimerAsm PROC EXPORT
pushfd             ;#1 backup flags register (4 Bytes)
pushad             ;#1 bakcup general purpose registers (8*4 Bytes)
mov eax, [esp+24h] ;#4 load interrupt handler pointer
push [esp+28h]     ;#? push handler parameter
call eax           ;#2 invoke interrupt handler
popad              ;#1 after return from interrupt handler, restore general purpose registers
popfd              ;#1 restore flags register
add esp, 08h       ;#3 pop interrupt handler pointer and the parameter
ret                ;#1 resume
doTimerAsm ENDP
```

Can anyone explain these numbers (and the `?`) to me? what do they mean? How is this auto-formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number after the hash is the byte-size of the line of assembly (as it would be if the instruction was assembled by the assembler). the `?` indicates that the size couldn't be calculated (in this case you are missing a size specifier on `[esp+28h]`, thus the assembler cannot tell if its a byte, word, dword or qword).

Comment: Thank you, though I don't see how this falls under the title of "auto-format". Just one question, if it doesn't know if it is a byte/word/etc., how does it compile? (it is a fact that it compiles and works fine)

Comment: Also, how do I give it this "size-specifier" you mentioned?

Comment: @baruch: the assembler probably just used a default/made an assumption (generally the word size of your target). A size specifier would look something like `push dword ptr [esp+28h]` or `push byte ptr [esp+28h]`.